# Confusion about the hidden subgroup formulation of graph isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, normal-subgroups, graph-isomorphism

I am going through [Quantum factoring, discrete logarithms and the hidden subgroup problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012084) by Richard Jozsa. On page 13, the author discussed the hidden subgroup problem (HSP) formulation of the graph isomorphism (GI) problem. I would like to make it sure that I get the development of the concept right.

Here both $A$ and $B$ are graphs of $n$-vertices. In each case, the vertices are labeled from $1$ to $n$. $M_A$ and $M_B$ are their adjacency matrices respectively. $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the permutation group of $n$ symbols. $C$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$. So, it is a graph of $2n$ vertices labeled $1 \ldots n, n+1 \ldots 2n$.

In the 5th paragraph of page 13, it is said that,

> The symmetry group $K$ of $C$ is evidently a subgroup of $\mathcal{P}_{2n}$ but we can
>   say more: since $A$ and $B$ are connected and $C$ is the disjoint union, any
>   symmetry of $C$ must either separately permute the sets of labels $L_A =
>  \left\{1, 2, . . . , n\right\}$ and $L_B = \left\{n + 1,...,2n\right\}$ or else swap the two sets
>   entirely. Thus if $H$ denotes the group $\mathcal{P}_n \times \mathcal{P}_n$ and $\sigma$ is the permutation
>   of $1,2, \ldots ,2n$ that swaps the two sets $S_A$ and $S_B$ in their listed order,
>   then $K$ will always be a subset of the group $G = H ∪ \sigma H$.

I understand that $ |H| = |\mathcal{P}_n \times \mathcal{P}_n| = n^2$. If we define $\sigma$ as a swap operation over $H$ so that it separately permutes $A$ and $B$ as they are in $C$, $\sigma$ has to deal with $n^2$ symbols while only $2n$ of them get swapped  keeping the position of the rest unchanged. This permutation maintains the **listed order** as the author says.

1. Where does this **listed order** come from? Is it just the ordered pair of vertices from the two input graphs, $A$ and $B$?
2. I understand that a **listed order** is the list or ordered pairs which remains intact after the permutation. **Shouldn't a list of ordered pairs of vertices from $\left(A, B\right)$ be preserved for any permutation over $2n$ symbols?**
3. Moreover, isn't $\sigma$ an element of a group which is of order 2?
4. Finally, why $K$ will always be a subset of the group $G = H \cup \sigma H$ ?

For reference the rest of the paragraph is:

> $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ containing all permutations that map $S_A$
>   and $S_B$ into themselves whereas $\sigma H$ is its one other coset,
>   of all permutations that swap the elements of $S_A$ and $S_B$ (in some
>   arbitrary order). Now we may easily verify the following facts:
>
> 1. if $A$ and $B$ are not isomorphic then $K$ lies entirely in $H$,
> 2. if $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic then exactly half of the members of $K$ are in $H$ and half are in $\sigma H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1)$ The listed order doesn't come from anywhere, *we put it there* at the beginning. The vertices of the graph $C$ are $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ (the ones belonging to $A$) and $\{n+1,\cdots,2n\}$ (belonging to $B$); anything enumerated by naturals and written down in order is automatically a listed order.

$(2)$ I think "listed order" just means "listed order," with no special technical meaning. The *edge sets* of $A$ and $B$ are each collections of ordered pairs of vertices, we combine these collections (after relabelling the vertices and edges in $B$ appropriately) to get the edge set of $C$. The symmetries in $K$ are certainly supposed to preserve the edge set of $C$. So if $\sigma$ is the permutation of $\{1,\cdots,2n\}$ which sends $i\mapsto i+n$ for $1\le i\le n$ and sends $j\mapsto j-n$ for $n<j\le 2n$ then $\sigma$ may not preserve the edge set of $C$, hence $\sigma$ may not be an element of $K$. We are not assuming that it is.

$(3)$ Yes, $\sigma$ is an involution (meaning $\sigma=\sigma^{-1}$ or $\sigma^2=e$) so $\langle\sigma\rangle=\{e,\sigma\}$ is a group of order $2$ which contains the permutation $\sigma$. This doesn't really seem very relevant.

$(4)$ We've already observed any symmetry in $K$ preserves the partition $\{A,B\}$ of $C$s vertex set; the set of *all* permutations preserving this partition is $H\cup\sigma H$ (hence $K\subseteq H\cup\sigma H$ follows). Let $\tau$ be any permutation in ${\cal P}_{2n}$ preserving this partition. Either $\tau(A)=A$ and $\tau(B)=B$ (no swapping occurs) and hence $\tau\in{\cal P}_n\times{\cal P}_n=H$, or else $\tau(A)=B$ and $\tau(B)=A$ (swapping occurs). Notice that the permutations preserving the partition $\{A,B\}$ are closed under inverses and composition so it is a subgroup $S$, and $\sigma$ is an element of $S$ just like $\tau$. We know $\sigma(A)=B$ and $\sigma(B)=A$, and we also know $\sigma^{-1}\circ\tau\in S$. Furthermore, $(\sigma^{-1}\circ\tau)(A)=A$ and $(\sigma^{-1}\circ\tau)(B)=B$, so $\sigma^{-1}\circ\tau$ is an element of ${\cal P}_n\times{\cal P}_n=H$, and so $\sigma^{-1}\tau\in H\implies \tau\in\sigma H$. Thus, $S\subseteq H\cup\sigma H$ and the reverse inclusion is clearly true, so $S=H\cup\sigma H$.

Comment: at the bottom of page 13 it says, "Given any element $\Pi \in G$ it is easy to check whether it lies in $H$ or $\sigma H$". This looks confusing. I thought $\Pi$ works on $n$ items while any element of $G$ should work on $2n$ items.

Comment: @OmarShehab We can reuse letters in math. Previously the author began a claim with "if there exists a $\Pi\in{\cal P}_n$ ..." in *that claim*, indeed $\Pi$ only operates on $n$ items. However in the paragraph you're quoting, it reboots the usage of that letter with "Given any element $\Pi\in G$," which automatically means $\Pi$ is some element of $G$ by definition in that new context.